# Conceptual doubts on convergency of $a^x$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms

I am studying Convergency and Divergency of series in Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight. This article is particularly giving me a hard time.

> *To show that the expansion of $a^x$ in ascending powers of $x$ is convergent for every value of $x$.*
>
> Here $\frac{u_{n}}{u_{n-1}}=\frac{x \log _{e} a}{n-1}$; and therefore $\lim _{n=\infty} \frac{u_{n}}{u_{n-1}}<1$ whatever be the value of x; hence the series is convergent.

Here are my questions :—

**Why is there $n-1$ in the denominator of $\frac{u_{n}}{u_{n-1}}=\frac{x \log _{e} a}{n-1}$.**

I've copied the exact article from the book. I think the $n-1$ may be a typo.

Also,

**Can anyone please explain me or at least give a rough idea of what's happening?**

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: I presume you are considering $$a^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(lx)^n}{n!}$$ where $l=\ln a$. Then if $u_n=(lx)^n/n!$ we have $u_n/u_{n-1}=lx/n$. But Hall and Knight's notation might differ. Of course as $n\to\infty$, $u_n/u_{n-1}\to0$ and that guarantees convergence.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanku. That's what I was thinking. The denominator should be $n$ not $n-1$. I think it is a typo because there are many typos in the book.

Comment: You should email Hall and Knight to tell them that. Or maybe hold a seance :-)

Comment: Maybe H&K like starting their series at $n=1$, so that $u_n=(lx)^{n-1)/(n-1)!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break the question down to smaller parts.

> expansion of $a^x$ in ascending powers of $x$

presumably means (Taylor expansion):

$$a^x = 1 + (\ln a)x + \frac{\ln^2 a}{2}x^2+\dots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{((\ln a) x)^n}{n!}$$

Now, presumably

> $u_n \triangleq \frac{((\ln a) x)^n}{n!}=\frac{((\ln a)x)((\ln a) x)^{n - 1}}{n(n-1)!}$

and therefore

$\frac{u_n}{u_{n-1}} = \frac{x\ln a}{n}$

which would suggest a typo indeed. Nevertheless, for the investigation of the convergence the exact form of the denominator is irrelevant. By simple change of definition ($n\geq 1$):

$u_n \triangleq \frac{((\ln a) x)^{n - 1}}{(n - 1)!} = \frac{(\ln a) x)((\ln a) x)^{n - 2}}{(n - 1)(n-2)!} $

which leads to the result as mentioned in the book.

In both cases, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{u_{n-1}} = 0.$